# Backbone sorting procedure. UI vs Data

Tags: backbone.js

My question is about the proper way to show a list of records using backbone.  Lets say you have a person model that you want to display to the user and allow them to sort by first name, last name, id....

The first instinct is to just have the view catch the event and re-render based on the users sort option.  The problem with this method is that it is U.I. driven and not data driven.

Second thoughts are to set the sorting attributes in the model since the collection does not contain attributes (though that seems would be the best option).  This method is at least data driven by setting the sorting attributes but is horribly redundant and if the sorting attributes are not stripped out on save they are sent to the server | local or...

Last thought is probably the correct one.  Create a second model that would be a control model used contain sorting/displaying properties.  My issues with this method is events and models can get very unruly.  If you expand beyond just a person model and make this a fairly large app you have a LOT of models and events and gets hard to manage.  The model-1 view has to catch the initial event, then have the collection trigger a custom event then the second model has to catch the custom event and render it.

Sorry for the long post, I am fairly new to backbone js and want to make sure I have the best practice grasp.  Thanks in advance for the help.  I hope I am at least on the correct track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just implemented this last night.

You can set a new collection `comparator` and then use the `sort` method on the collection. `sort` will fire a `reset` event, which you can use in your view to re-render the list.

Here is my view, which contains a select box that allows the user to choose how to sort the data:

```
App.HouseListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.house-list',
    initialize: function() {
        App.houseCollection.bind('reset', this.populateList, this);

    },
    events: {
        'change .sort':'sort',
    },
    populateList: function(collection) {
        this.$('ul').html('');
        _.each(collection.models, function(model) {
            var view = new App.HouseListElemView({model:model});
            this.$('ul').append(view.el);
        });
    }, 
    sort: function(e) {
        var sort_by = $(e.srcElement.selectedOptions[0]).attr('data-sort-by');
        App.houseCollection.comparator = function(house) {
            return house.get(sort_by);
        }
        App.houseCollection.sort();
    },
});
```

Hope this helps

EDIT: Implemented `@mu is too short`'s suggestion:

```
App.Houses = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: App.House,
    url: API_URL,
    _sort_by: 'price',
    sort_houses_by: function(sort_by) {
        this._sort_by = sort_by;
        this.sort();
    },
    comparator: function(house) {
        return house.get(this._sort_by);
    },
});


App.houseCollection = new App.Houses();

App.HouseListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.house-list',
    initialize: function() {
        App.houseCollection.bind('reset', this.populateList, this);

    },
    events: {
        'change .sort':'sort',
    },
    populateList: function(collection) {
        this.$('ul').html('');
        _.each(collection.models, function(model) {
            var view = new App.HouseListElemView({model:model});
            this.$('ul').append(view.el);
        });
    }, 
    sort: function(e) {
        var sort_by = $(e.srcElement.selectedOptions[0]).data('sort-by');
        App.houseCollection.sort_houses_by(sort_by);
    },
});
```

Comment: A method on the collection to swap the `comparator` and `sort` would be a better approach; then that method could just set `this._sort_by` and the `comparator` would `return house.get(this._sort_by)`. And you can just say `.data('sort-by')` instead of `.attr('data-sort-by')`.

Comment: should populateList() be render() instead?

Comment: Maybe, the real `render()` might do more stuff that just draw the list.